# separating `multinom` estimations by response (nnet package) in R

Tags: r, multinomial

In a multinomial logistic regression, one uses a set of covariates (x1, x2, ... xn)  to predict the value of a discrete variable y that, for instance,  can take the values of "outcome a", "outcome b", and "outcome c". In `R`, the most popular way to fit a multinomial logit is to use the `multinom` function under the **nnet** package.

When running `model <- multinom(outcome ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=data)`, 
`summary(model)` would always present the estimations of each outcome together:

```
Coefficients:
               (Intercept)          x1           x2             x3 
outcome b       0.7990265   -0.9426088    0.2295875    -0.01346151
outcome c       0.6516952   -1.0174237    0.3367977    -0.43912425
```

My question is: how do we present statistical estimations that predict "outcome b" and "outcome c" (assuming "a" is the base category) separately?

Ideally, I would like to use `stargazer()` and present one coefficient table for `outcome b`, and another table for `outcome c`, any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `Coefficients` table into data frame and then delete/remove not needed rows maybe?

Like in the following example:

```
lmfit <- lm(mpg ~ wt + cyl, mtcars)
ab = summary(lmfit)
bc = ab$coefficients
bc = as.data.frame(bc)

wt = bc[c(-1, -3), ]
wt
```